# How to Translate All These Objects At Once?

Tags: objects, interface, workflow, transforms, unity

I am new to Blender so this question is probably a very easy one to answer.
I have this minecart obstacle I made with 17 different objects that can be seen in the "Layers" Tab. I would just like to know how to select all the objects at once in the "Layers" Tab and translate them to the origin so the minecart as a whole is at origin. Is that possible? Right now the minecart is to the left of the origin.
Thank you! :)
[image: Minecart translation]

Comment: Given that your tags include unity, I assume you wish to export this. If it is intended to be a single model you may wish to join each mesh into one by selecting them all and using ctrl-j

Comment: What you call the "layers tab" is called the **[OUTLINER](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/outliner.html?highlight=outliner)** It shows you the objects present in the scene. **DO NOT CONFUSE IT WITH LAYERS**. Layers are in a different place. Please read the following link to familiarize yourself with how layers work in blender. It will save you headaches down the line: https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/layers.html?highlight=layers#layers

Comment: Okay I will. Thank you for your wisdom and for correcting me before I went any further. @cegaton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select them one by one in the "outliner" (not layers) by <kbd>Shift</kbd> clicking on each object's name, one by one.
or you can go to the 3d View where your objects are and press <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice to select them all.

To move them to the origin (0,0,0 at the center of the 3d view) , first press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to make the cursor go to the origin.
then (while the objects still all selected ) press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> , and choose *selected to 3d cursor*.

Comment: Note that *Selected to 3D cursor* will snap each object to the center **individually**. To snap them while maintaining their relative positions, use *Selected to 3D cursor (offset)*